# multiple element manipulation depending on element data xquery

Tags: xml, groovy, xquery, soapui

I've been struggling for about 4 hours+ now on this and have come close but no cigar. I am trying to change the numbers inside the node catID (they range from 1 - 30 odd+) to text (so 1:abc,2:bca,3:acb etc)

the XML:

```
<return>
  <cat>
   <catId>1</catId>
   <foo>134</foo>
   <bar>431</bar>
  </cat>
<cat>
  <catId>2</catId>
  <foo>134</foo>
  <bar>432</bar>
</cat>
<cat>
  <catId>3</catId>
  <foo>314</foo>
  <bar>431</bar>
</cat>
</return>
```

the code i have so far

```
<return>
{
for $x in //cat
order by $x//cat/number() ascending
return <c>
<d>{replace($x//CatId,"14","test")}</d>
</c>
}
</return>
```

Now i have two problems, firstly if the "14" is changed to just a "1" then everything with "1" changes to "test" so "14" becomes `test4` lol..

Secondly, the interesting part i haven't gotten to yet is: How does one accomplish such a feat of iterating and changing a multipart XML and change the element value based on element data (from a map most likely)? I am busy going through this site https://www.progress.com/xquery/resources/tutorials/tour/combining-and-restructuring-nodes-in-xquery
but this is a little out of my understanding.... Should I just give up and do this in groovy? The tool I am using is SoapUI open source and this is in a property transfer (property to property, not response)

Comment: XQuery can't update data, that is what XQuery Update is for. You need to use a processor what supports this. The other alternative is to recreate your XML structure and change the values in your new output accordingly.

Comment: So your saying i should try `upd:replaceElementContent()` ? very interesting (now that i know I will try and update later)